# Servicestack A potentially dangerous Request.Form

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to post HTML content to a ServiceStack endpoint but keep getting the  "A potentially dangerous Request.Form" error.

How do you stop this in servicestack - non of the standard tweaks seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [ASP.NET Request Validation exception](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770147) that is thrown before it reaches ServiceStack (or before executing any ASP.NET Handler).

You can revert to relaxed validation mode by specifying it in your Web.Config:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```